Unable to Access WordPress on cPanel with Python/Django + React-Admin Setup
I have a shared hosting setup using cPanel where I’ve deployed a Python application with Django as the backend and React-admin as the frontend. In addition, I’ve installed WordPress in a subdirectory (e.g., karmodir.ir/wp/). However, whenever I try to access the WordPress subdirectory, I always get redirected to the React-admin frontend, and the WordPress site shows as a blank page.
I’ve tried various configurations, including modifying .htaccess and routing in React-admin. The React-admin app is running fine, but I can’t bypass it to view the WordPress site in the subdirectory.
export const App = () => (
  <CacheProvider value={cacheRtl}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        {/* redirection for /wp/ */}
        <Route path="/wp/*" element={<Navigate to="/wp/" replace />} />
        {/* Main routing for SiteAdmin */}
        <Route path="/*" element={<SiteAdmin />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </CacheProvider>
);

and here is .htaccess:
# Redirect /wp/ to the correct WordPress path
RewriteEngine On

# Ensure the rule only applies to /wp/ requests
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wp/
RewriteRule ^wp/(.*)$ http://karmodir.ir/wp/$1 [L,R=301]

# DO NOT REMOVE. CLOUDLINUX PASSENGER CONFIGURATION BEGIN
PassengerAppRoot "/home/karmodir/jkar/jkar"
PassengerBaseURI "/"
PassengerPython "/home/karmodir/virtualenv/jkar/jkar/3.10/bin/python"
# DO NOT REMOVE. CLOUDLINUX PASSENGER CONFIGURATION END

# DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY. CLOUDLINUX ENV VARS CONFIGURATION BEGIN
<IfModule Litespeed>
</IfModule>
# DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY. CLOUDLINUX ENV VARS CONFIGURATION END


What wordpress sub-route/directory are you trying to access. From what I see here your code should create a render loop, e.g. navigate to some "/wp/*****" path and redirect to "/wp/" which is matched by "/wp/*" and again the redirect is effected, and this is exactly what I see happen when I copy/paste your code into a running sandbox. What does SiteAdmin render? I suspect you need to push this "/wp/*" redirect down the route tree. Can you [edit] to include a complete [mcve] of your code?

thanks, I found the following solution posted

The following code for .htaccess works:
RewriteEngine On

# Rule 1: Ensure requests for /wp/ are sent to WordPress
# If the request is for /wp/ or any subdirectory, it should go to WordPress
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wp/
RewriteRule ^wp/(.*)$ /wp/$1 [L]

# Rule 2: Ensure any file or directory under /wp/ is served by WordPress
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^wp/(.*)$ /wp/index.php [QSA,L]

# Rule 3: Redirect everything else (not starting with /wp/) to React Admin's index.html
# This will catch all other requests and route them to React Admin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp/  # Exclude any requests starting with /wp/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html [QSA,L]

